# Method of integrating a certain persons Twitter account into iOS App

Tags: ios, twitter

In my app so far, I have to implement all the Twitter posts from a certain individual into a table view, and it automatically updates when the person tweets a certain post. Is it possible to mention a certain individual e.g. @John.. If it is possible, how can I do it? If not just let me know and I will delete this question as it could be too ambitious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean. I do a little!

There is a quick and easy way of doing this! One easy way is to use Twitters own SDK called Fabric. [See Here](http://fabric.io)

See this link for the timeline stuff and integration to your app [Documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/index.html)

This should help you out!

P.S. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I'll be sure to check it out

Comment: Just installed Fabric onto my Mac and integrated it into my app and use the timeline feature. It works. Thanks for suggestion. Many Thanks.